# How to automatically replicate a running VM on ESXi to a computer running locally VMWare Player or VMWare Fusion?

Tags: replication, virtual-machine, offline

The specific use case I'm dealing in our company is the following:

On a ESXi server, a dedicated VM is running to host a demo environment of a software solution. This demo environment is maintained updated by the development and maintenance team.

At specific points in time, people form sales need to take with them a copy of the latest demo environment (the VM) on their laptop to make customer's demos/presentations.

I wonder if there is a tool to automate this kind of operation silently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.
VMware themself make a product called vCenter Converter which is available here http://www.vmware.com/uk/products/converter/

When using the standalone client choose to convert..

Source : VMware Infrastructure virtual machine
Destination : VMware Workstation or Other VMWare Virtual Machine

You should then be able to open in in Player or Fusion.

*This will require the VMs to be off, if you don't want to turn them off you could clone them first (only available if you aren't using the free ESXi Hypervisor - thus the paid one)

Hope this helps :)